# How many $6$ digit numbers are there that doesn't have number $2$ in them and have two $1$?

Tags: combinatorics

Is this the right way to calculate it?

1. If the first number is $1$, then there are $5$ ways to choose another $1$ and $4$ digits left that can be equal to $8$ different numbers
   So in total $5\cdot8^4=20480$
2. If the first number isn't $1$, then it can have $7$ different values. We can choose two $1$ in $5\cdot4$ ways and there are left $3$ digits that can be equal to $8$ different values.
   In total $7\cdot5\cdot4\cdot8^3=71680$.

Adding all of this I get $92160$ different numbers.

Comment: We can choose two units in $5\cdot4/2$ ways.

Comment: Other that the mistake pointed by @kabenyuk, your approach seems correct. Choosing two ones out of five positions calls for combinations, not permutations as ones are indistinguishable.

Comment: As alternative method,  first include those that begin with $0$,  then subtract off those that do begin with $0$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Vasya and with lulu

Comment: In part 2 the ways to *choose* the positions of the two $1$s out of $5$ positions is ${5\choose 2} = \frac {5!}{3!2!} = \frac {5\cdot 4(3\cdot 2\cdot 1)}{(3\cdot 2\cdot 1)\cdot (2\cdot 1)}= \frac {5\cdot 4}2$.  Alternatively.... There are $5$ places for the first one and $4$ for the second one but as the two ones are indistiguishable switching the orders of the ones would be the same so we must divide by the number of ways to switch the orders... that argument is *why* ${a\choose b} = \frac {a\cdot(a-1)....(a-b+1)}{b\cdot (b-1)....1}=\frac {\frac {a!}{(a-b)!}}{b!}=\frac {a!}{(a-b)!b!}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method to solve this.

**Case 1: The digit '0' does not appear**

This means that we have to choose numbers for $4$ vacant positions ($2$ out of $6$ will be filled by the digit $1$), and for each of these we can choose from $\{x: x \in [3,9], x\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Hence there are $7$ choices for each digit.
Also, we can choose the positions for the two $1's$ in $\binom 62$ ways. Hence, total numbers are:
$$N_1=\binom 62 7^4$$

**Case 2: The digit '0' necessarily appears**

Firstly let us not consider the constraint that the first digit can't be $0$. Then, the total number of such six digit strings must be:
$$N_2=\binom 62 8^4-\binom 62 7^4$$

Here the first term represents the total numbers in which the digit $0$ may appear, and from this we subtract the number in which $0$ doesn't appear, hence $N_2$ is the number of such strings where $0$ appears atleast once. Finally we apply the constraint that $0$ must not be the first digit. There would be $\binom 52 8^3$ such digits ($0$ is fixed as first digit, we select $2$ positions out of $5$ for the $1's$, and have $8$ choices each for the rest of the $3$ positions left).

Thus, we have finally:
$$N_3=N_2-\binom 52 8^3$$ digits for this case.

Thus, the total is $N_1+N_3=56320$, which disagrees with your calculations(your error has been pointed out by other commenters, hence this answer doesn't deal with that) but agrees with @Bulbasaur's answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{\text{Alternative Approach:}}$

By using exponential generating functions:

İf there are two $1's$ then the exponential generating function of it : $$\bigg(\frac{x^2}{2!} \bigg)$$

If there is not any two and do not have any restriction over the others then the exponential generating function of others : $$\bigg(1 + x +\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} +\frac{x^4}{4!}  \bigg)^8$$ , because of there are two $1's$ , we have maximum $4$ times same number.Moreover , because of any two and ones will not be used again , the exponential is $8$

Now find the coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion of $$\bigg(1 + x +\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} +\frac{x^4}{4!}  \bigg)^8 \times \bigg(\frac{x^2}{2!} \bigg)$$ and multiply it by $6!$. (you can also find the coefficient of $\frac{x^6}{6!}$)

However , realize that this calculation counts the strings that start with zero , so we must subtract them from the result. Now, lets assume that it start with zero and have two $1's$.To do that , find the expansion of $$\bigg(1 + x +\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} +\frac{x^4}{4!}  \bigg)^8 \times \bigg(\frac{x^2}{2!} \bigg)$$
, after that find the coefficient of $x^5$ and multiply it by $5!$.(you can also find the coefficient of $\frac{x^5}{5!}$)
Now , it is the time for subtracting them..

*[Calculation by wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expanded+form+of+%281%2Bx+%2B+x%5E2+%2F2+%2Bx%5E3+%2F6+%2Bx%5E4+%2F24%29%5E8+%28x%5E2+%2F+2+%29)*

$$6! \times \frac{256}{3} - 5! \times \frac{128}{3}=61440-5120=56320$$

Unfortunately, your answer is wrong..

Comment: Is there any way to find the expansion of exponential generating function without calculator(or Wolfram Alpha) ?

Comment: @SDas For some restrictions it can be done by hand using $e^x$.For example distributing $7$ distinct balls into $3$ distinct boxes such that each boxes have at least $2$ balls in it , this can be found by $(e^x -x-1)^3$.However, for more complex cases i do not know any easy technique.I am sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version:
Start with two ones, no twos, then the number of all possible combinations of
six digit numbers (except that I am not taking into account a leading '0'digit for now)
is
$$ \frac{6!}{4!2!}\times 8^4=15\times 8^4=61440.$$
Now subtract all such numbers with a leading zero.
That will include all 5, 4, 3 and 2 digit numbers.
This number of combinations is
$$ \frac{5!}{3!2!}\times 8^3=5120.$$
Hence, the desired number is
$$ \frac{6!}{4!2!}-\frac{5!}{3!2!}=56320$$
in agreement with the other proposed solutions by @Bulbasaur and @Ritam_Dasgupta.

Answer (score 0):

Digit **1** will *not* be the first digit $\binom52/\binom62=\frac23$ of the time
and **0** *will* be the first digit $\frac23\frac18 = \frac1{12}$ of the time

Thus total valid numbers = $\frac{11}{12}\binom62 8^4 = 56320$